# recreate view of fragment via button

Tags: android, fragment, reload, android-fragmentactivity, recreate

I've got a FragmentActivity which show the correct fragment, using a ViewPager. I added a Fragment StatePagerAdapter to the ViewPager. If I push a button at a Fragment, it should be recreated (onCreateView should be called again). The fragments are articles and if the user is offline, I'll show him "please check your networkconnection" and a button to reload. The button called a method in the FragmentActivity, but I don't know how implement it. Maybe I can destroy and recreate the current Fragment?

here the important part of the FragmentActivity:

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_page_slider);
    ...
    pages = datahandler.getCount(...);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.articlePager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(startPosition);
    fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(pages);
}
public void reloadData(View v)
{
    // TODO
    ((ArticlePageFragment)fragments.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())).refresh();
}
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        Fragment fragment = new ArticlePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        ...
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragments.add(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return pages;
    }
}
```

and the Fragment itself:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    activity = getActivity();
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_article_page, container, false);

    CacheDataHandler cdh = new CacheDataHandler(activity);
    cdh.open();
    String htmlData = cdh.loadData();
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reload_article_data).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    webView = ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.articleFragment));
    refresh();
    ...
    return rootView;
}
public void refresh()
{
    ...
    if (htmlData == null)
    {
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reload_article_data).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.loadData(defaultdata,"text/html", "UTF-8");
    }
    else
    {
        webView.loadData(htmlData,"text/html", "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

and the fragment_article_page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/articleFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reload_article_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="reloadData"
        android:text="@string/btn_txt_reload_data"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**
added a `private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments` in FragmentActivity and transfer the code for manipulating the view in an extra `refresh`Method, look ahead. All works fine, if I only click on the first or second Fragment (index 0 and 1). Otherwise I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. How to initialize and fill the ArrayList?

Comment: See : ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626956/how-to-refresh-fragment-tab-content-on-button-click-android-eclipse)